# why does (00123 + 34351) return 34434 in javascript, java and python ? The correct answer is 34474

Tags: javascript, python, math, addition, radix

```
console.log(00123 + 34351); //in javascript, outputs 34434
print(00123 + 34351); //in python, outputs 34434
```

in javascript, outputs 34434
in python, outputs 34434

However removing the leading zeroes i.e (123 + 34351) gives the correct answer, which is 34474

Comment: Only in Python 2.x... https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#integers

Comment: Because they interpret 00 as octal prefix, although, newer python no longer allows this and requires 0o prefix instead. 0o123 is 83 decimal, makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`0` is a common prefix for octal, for which the decimal number is 83. Doing

```
console.log(00123+34351)
```

is equivalent to

```
console.log(83+34351)
```

edit: note that in python 3+ the prefix is `0o`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Java, but in JavaScript and in Python 2, numbers starting with `0` are octal numbers, i.e. `00123` is actually `83` in decimal.

**JavaScript:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Numeric_literals

Answer (score 1):

No, the correct answer is, indeed 34434 (base 10).  A number with a leading 0 in many languages is octal, so your addition operation is 123 (base 8) + 34351 (base 10).  Convert the octal integer to decimal, and you'll see the rationale.